# Using TNotificationCenter.OnReceiveLocalNotification

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7, notificationcenter

I'm trying to catch the message in NotificationCenter in order to use it for other purposed, when i receive a notification into my device thru gcm php server i tried to catch the message with NotificationCenter:NotificationCenterReceiveLocalNotification Event but unfortunartly it did NOT.

```pascal
procedure Tdm.NotificationCenterReceiveLocalNotification(Sender: TObject;   ANotification: TNotification);  
begin   
           ShowMessage(ANotification.Name) ;   
end;
```

Any idea what will be the error or the mistake ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get a **remote notification** (PUSH - GCM) with NotificationCenter that handles **local notifications**.

To handle push you have to use **TPushEvents** component, **OnPushReceived** event, being more specific.

Comment: What will be the settings of TPushEvents ? is it just to drop this component and click onPushReceived event ?

Comment: Here's a tuto http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Creating_the_Application ... If you dont use kinvey or parse you will have to implement your own provider

Comment: I Havent tested it without a provider!

Comment: Thanks Agustin for your Support,